# How to recover my password using finger print in HP client security?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

In my HP Laptop, I use both `password` and `fingerprint` for login. Unfortunalely i did not use my laptop long while. now I forgot my password. still i can able to access my system using my fingureprint.

The issue is some times the fingureprint not working properly. Now I forced to reset my password or recover my old password. Even I prefere to recover my old password. Any one help me here please?

I use `Windows7` 64 bit.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have an admin account?

Comment: If you have an admin account, I think you can change the password without knowing the current password.

Comment: I was able to use my print to [view current stored passwords in HP Client Security](https://superuser.com/questions/952328/view-passwords-in-hp-client-security/959600#959600) but not the Windows one. Maybe useful if you unwisely share passwords.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works if you have an **admin account**, or you can borrow the rights(not sure about the later):

- Log in to your pc
- Open a command prompt window with admin privileges ([how to open cmd with admin rights](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))
- Type `net user`
- Look for your user account (or the account whose password you have to change)
- Type `net user {username}`, replace **username** with the account user name. eg. `net user john`
- Type`net user {username} *`, for example `net user john *`
- Type in the new password, press enter
- Retype it and hit enter

Read [it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149427) from Microsoft. A little bit more [information](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ss/windows-7-password-reset-walkthrough_11.htm).

Comment: I am not getting any inormation. here is the `cmd output: `
C:\Windows\system32>net user
User accounts for \\INCHCMLP01756

--------------------------------------------------------
admin                    Administrator            Guest
The command completed successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>net user {mb112830}
The user name could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.`

Comment: The out put isn't clear, wht was the output when you tried the **net userusrname * **

Comment: @3gwebtrain Did you run it from an Admin cmd?

Comment: yes, I am a administrator.  I run cmd using admin rights. leave it all, is there a way to see the current password being used?

Comment: I have heard you can,There is a Linux distro caled Kali Linux, specially created for penetration testing, it has tools to do this. But I do not think it is worth doing so.

Comment: oh.. any other way to get my password here?

Comment: [This](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) is one of the tools it uses. But I haven't tried it and you can only find the password if it's a common one because it uses rainbowtables, not brute force.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24219/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-rogue).

Comment: I you do not mind, execute the command **net user [usrname]**, and look for this line _User may change password_, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

One time when the Fingerprint works to log in navigate back to the user info and change password.

***Once you are  logged in you need not remember the pass to reset it  (unless 8.1 / 10 changed that)***

Comment: I am trying to reset my password, but i am asking to fill my `current` password. where can i see the user info?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lusrmgr.msc tool.

1. Press Windows + R to open Run prompt.
2. Type lusrmgr.msc in the box and click OK
3. Select Users on the left panel.
4. Right click on the user you want and click Change Password.
5. Follow the instructions.