# View passwords in HP client security?

Tags: security

Windows 10 upgrade on Windows 7 says I should uninstall HP Client Security because it's incompatible with Windows 10.

I would like to know beforehand that no passwords will be lost, but I could not find a list of them in HP Client Security while I've saved at least two there (Windows login and another one I forgot).

Is such possible?

Comment: If you cannot find an option in the client itself to view the passwords, they likely are not stored, in a format that can be viewed.

Comment: @Ramhound Well that sucks. Seems i'm locked in to 7 until HP makes it compatible with 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated to version 8.3.7.1864 (Home > Advanced Settings > About HP Client Security) and rebooted, then was able to swipe an enrolled finger again after clicking Home > Password Manager, and saw a list of logins of which the passwords can be shown by select, Edit, View, Cancel on each item.

[Reportedly](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/HP-Client-Security-Manager-Incompatible-With-Windows-10/m-p/5173497/highlight/true#M303346), the latest version ([8.3.12.1991, sp71565.exe (147 MB)](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=ob_149745_1)) is compatible with Windows 10, but the Win10Pro upgrade still wants to uninstall it.